Preventing splitting nautilus windows by drive
I have 3 drives on my device and opening either of them creates a separate "group" of windows for each of the drives. I often use the keyboard shortcut "alt + `" which is like alt-tab for windows of the same program.
My problem is, that Nautilus for some reason treats each drive as a separate group so if I have 2 nautilus windows from 2 separate drives open, when I press "alt + `" it doesn't switch between them. "alt + `" only works if both the windows are in a directory that is on the same drive.
Is there any way to merge the windows into one group so that "alt+`" cycles through all of them and not just the current drive?

Disabled "Show Mounted Drives" setting in Dock settings and it started behaving like I want.
